# If the date picker field is clicked, both the date ranges calendars has to be displayed

Tags: javascript

The following is my code:

```
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
```

What changes should I make?

Comment: provide your full code or preferably link to a fiddle

Comment: please provide the following: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider what you would like to do exactly:
The datepicker fills a date into an input field.
You should use two fileds so you could store both dates in them.
If you would like to display pickers you should use a different event listener on a

- containing element
- when loading the page that generates the fields etc..

:)
But I also think as @Shreyas: you should include more details about this!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range. . . Please look into this..I have used the same code. .But what I want is that When I click on the field I need both from and to calender displayed.

Comment: Date Range :- Consider this as field X.                             

If I click on the field X, the following should be displayed 

"From" with calender below         "To" with calender below

Comment: Hey, There is a sample code there which actually does that. What is the difference between that sample and what you want exactly?